# Extract the “path” of a data point through a decision tree in sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm working with decision trees in python's scikit learn. Unlike many use cases for this, I'm not so much interested in the accuracy of the classifier at this point so much as I am extracting the specific path a data point takes through the tree when I call .predict() on it. Has anyone done this before? 
I know this can be done in R using rpart, however trying hard to do same using Python. Any pointers would be helpful

Comment: Are you looking for a visualization?

Comment: i am looking for some way to see the path followed by a new prediction in Dec path tree. or the set of rules that led to a prediction. I see something similar in R in rpart package. In Python/Scikitlearn i couldn't find anything so far during my research. I tried converting the complete Dectree into a python code with if/else but that doesnt seem to be a scalable solution in my case, as the code contains over 200,000 lines.

Comment: Honestly, the simplest way is probably to install graphviz and then use `sklearn.tree.export_graphviz` (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html) to visualize. You can use the `decision_path` attribute of the tree, but it's a little more complicated.